# Difference between classification methods with Laspy

Tags: python, lidar, classification, las, laspy

I need to add classification to create a LAS file. I used the code below but it was miss-classified. Is there any problem with the code? And what is the difference between:

```
out.file classification
```

and

```
 outfile.Raw_Classification

      hdr = laspy.header.Header()
      outfile = laspy.file.File("output.las", mode="w", header=hdr)
      allx = scanne[:,0] 
      ally = scanne[:,1]
      allz = scanne[:,2]

      xmin =np.min(allx)
      ymin =np.min(ally)
      zmin =np.min(allz)

      outfile.header.offset = [xmin,ymin,zmin]
      outfile.header.scale = [0.001,0.001,0.001]
      outfile.x = allx
      outfile.y = ally
      outfile.z = allz
      outfile.Raw_Classification  = scanne[:,3]
      print(hdr)
      outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

LAS 1.2 has a classification byte, which is 8 bits.  However 3 of those bits are used for the flags (withheld, synthetic, and keypoint).

With laspy, `classification` accesses the 5 bits that LAS 1.2 allows for the classification number.  2^5 is 32, meaning you can store 32 classes (0-31) in that 5-bit integer.  It doesn't touch the flag bits.

`raw_classification` gives no special handling to the flag bits and instead accesses all 8 of the bits, treating it as an 8-bit integer.  This would let you store a number above 31 in this byte field (2^8 == 256, 0-255), but it also uses those flag bits to do so.  The implication is that softwares that actually follow the spec will only read the 5 bits that the spec defines when determining the classification, giving you a different number.

Read through the spec, especially page 8 to understand this better:

https://www.asprs.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/asprs_las_format_v12.pdf

Comment: H i thank you for the response. but when i try classification, I got the error Laspy Exception: Invalid Data: Packed Length is Greater than allowed. how can i fix this

Comment: Sounds like you might be trying to set values >31.  As above, that's not allowed if you want wide compatibility with LAS 1.2 files between software packages.

Comment: In fact i am dealing with 22 classes, the labels type is uint32 and the data is float32.

Comment: Try converting to uint8?  `labels.astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: I got the same error : LaspyException: Invalid Data: Packed Length is Greater than allowed.