LiDAR point cloud has no classfications [laspy], trying to classify and filter ground points
I have a .las file of data collected on a road, and I would like to get only the ground and points 'below' ground (potholes, other indentations, for example). However, when I load the data, it seems there are no classifications:
pc1 = laspy.read('mylaz.laz')
xyz = np.vstack((pc1.x, pc1.y, pc1.z)).transpose()
xyz

>>> array([[-4.54700123,  2.65995164, -1.54027404],
       [-5.00620123,  2.91695164, -1.53607404],
       [-4.54670123,  2.69455164, -1.53577404],
       ...,
       [37.49779877, 44.22565164,  7.35862596],
       [37.41159877, 44.93535164,  6.84772596],
       [37.55939877, 45.72255164,  6.30302596]])

xyz.shape
>>> (26766229, 3)

print(np.unique(pc1.classification))
>>> [0]


Is this an issue of data collection? Is there a reason there would be no classifications? What approach can I take to "trim" the point cloud to ONLY have the road and depressions in the road?

see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/334088/difference-between-classification-methods-with-laspy

even inspecting xyz.raw_classification, same thing

Use the Cloth Simulation Filter in CloudCompare.
